# Driver's side front wheel placement

Tags: suspension, dodge, duster

I have problem with the front end on a 75 Duster. The front wheel on driver's side moved forward hitting fender in front of wheel. There is a half finger gap in front of wheel, three fingers behind. Just replaced upper control arm bushings, cam bolts, idler arm, and ball joint. The tire is still off center. Checked strut rod, bushings look good, and rod is straight. Everyone is saying the strut rod is causing the issue. Should I just replace it too?

Comment: what do you mean when you say the front wheel "moved forward?"
was there an accident?
what do you mean when you say the tire is "off center?"
do you mean the wheel is off center?
off center when viewed from what angle?
you replaced cam bolts?
did you align the vehicle after replacing all the mentioned parts?

Comment: if you look at front tire it is closer to front of wheel well then back all part where replaces by shop but couldn't align because tire was still off center and mechanic never did strutrod replacement before so off to another shop with older mechanics ,friends of my .should have took to them first